# PIN Management for mobile

Tags: mobilesdk

We have developed a mobile app using your mobile sdk and are introducing the PIN feature.  It's great that you've provided and OOB solution.  However, I'm not clear on how to handle the "what ifs" when we go live.  If Users forget their PIN, what steps do they have to take?  Can individual device PINs be reset remotely by an administrator?